# Max attribute in html date input is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to set the max date for date input field in HTML. It worked fine in Chrome, but in Firefox it is allowing user to enter any date even out of the max date specified. Any quick / easy work-around fix for this?

I tried setting max="9999-12-31" but for some reason the Firefox browser doesn't care what's given in max attribute.

```
<input type="date" max="9999-12-31">
```

I want to restrict the date input up-till "9999-12-31" in firefox browser

Comment: This works in Firefox. Can you clarify a date that does not work? There is no 4 digit year higher than this.

Answer (score -1):

This is working in firefox, Check your browser version or make sure `<!DOCTYPE html>` is added in your page.

Enter a date before 1980-01-01:

```
<input type="date" name="bday" max="1979-12-31">
```

Enter a date after 2000-01-01:

```
<input type="date" name="bday" min="2000-01-02"><br>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. As demonstrated by this https://jsfiddle.net/mvqj2kdx/ not only you can select a year higher than max with the selector, but you have to type up to 6 year digit before the months are selected (try typing just '1'). Make sure to have a  "YYYY-MM-DD" as the mask to test.